# JENKINS: Unable to load the mojo 'test'

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

When I am running build from jenkins. I am getting below error.The command I am running is mvn -P dev clean install

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M1:test (default-test) on project OMS: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M1:test failed: Unable to load the mojo 'test' (or one of its required components) from the plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M1': com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors:
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 1) No implementation for org.codehaus.plexus.languages.java.jpms.LocationManager was bound.
[ERROR] while locating org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefirePlugin
[ERROR] at ClassRealm[plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M1, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@5c647e05]
[ERROR] while locating org.apache.maven.plugin.Mojo annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M1:test)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 1 error
[ERROR] role: org.apache.maven.plugin.Mojo
[ERROR] roleHint: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M1:test
```

But if I run the same command on the build machine manually. The build is getting successful. why I am getting error? I can't make the changes into pom as it is building successful while running mvn command directly.

Comment: What are Maven versions on CI and on your machine?

Comment: I have tried with 3.2.3, 3.3.3, 3.5.3, 3.6.0